# JavaScript method chaining challenge

Tags: javascript, method-chaining

(This question is not really restricted to the language so please feel free to submit solution in other languages too.)

I was just wondering if it would be possible to write something like this in JavaScript:

```
// Wait 3 seconds and then say our message in an alert box
wait(3).then(function(){alert("Hello World!");});
```

Where the traditional way would be to write

```
// Wait 3 seconds and then say our message in an alert box
setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello World!");}, 3000);
```

Sorry if this is a noob question :p

Comment: I think you answered your own question.... what is wrong with the second block of code?

Comment: @Zoidberg: The title is method chaining so the thing here is not really about getting it to work but getting it to work using method chaining.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can write it easily:

```
function wait(delay) {
  return {
    then: function (callback) {
      setTimeout(callback, delay*1000);
    }
  };
}

wait(3).then(function(){alert("Hello World!");});
```

If you want to go in-deep, I recommend you to read about [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) and [partial function application](http://ejohn.org/blog/partial-functions-in-javascript/), those topics are really interesting.

Comment: @cemkalyoncu: I'm a fast typist, and I use Vim-like edition everywhere :-D

Answer (score 14):

Yet another version, without closure:

```
function wait(seconds) {
    if(this instanceof wait)
        this.delay = seconds;
    else return new wait(seconds);
}

wait.prototype.then = function(callback) {
    setTimeout(callback, this.delay * 1000);
};
```

With some more code, you can even call the functions repeatedly:

```
function wait(seconds) {
    if(this instanceof wait)
        this.delay = seconds;
    else return new wait(seconds);
}

wait.prototype.then = function(callback) {
    setTimeout(callback, this.delay * 1000);
    return this;
};

wait.prototype.wait = function(seconds) {
    this.delay += seconds;
    return this;
};

var start = new Date;
function alertTimeDiff() {
    alert((new Date - start)/1000);
}

wait(1).then(alertTimeDiff).wait(3).then(alertTimeDiff);
```

Comment: @Christoph: Your approach is good and is what I think to be more comprehensive than CMS'. But then again he answered the question correctly faster so I gave the correct answer to him :p

Answer (score 2):

Chaining is rather used to execute multiple methods on one object. So you would rather consider the function as the object and set the timeout there:

```
Function.prototype.callAfter = function(delay) {
    setTimeout(this, delay*1000);
};

(function(){alert("Hello World!");}).callAfter(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do OO Javascript, then yes, you can do method chaining.

Some of the popular JavaScript frameworks do this.  [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) does this by returning the jQuery object for functions that usually wouldn't return a value.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a [little helper](https://github.com/0x01/mu-ffsm/) to create APIs like this in a somewhat consistent way, maybe you like it.

```
// > npm i mu-ffsm # install node dependency
var mkChained = require('mu-ffsm');
```

The idea is that you construct a fluent builder with some initial state of type `S` by calling an entry function. Then each chained call transitions the state to a new state.

The value you get from chaining a bunch of calls can be executed as a function, which calls exit to construct a value from that state and any options you pass in.

- entry : * ⟶ S
- transition : (S ⟶ *) ⟶ S
- exit : S ⟶ (* ⟶ *)

For example

```
var API = mkChained({
  0:    function(opt)    {return ;/* create initial state */},
  then: function(s, opt) {return s; /* new state */},
  whut: function(s, opt) {return s; /* new state */},
  1:    function(s, opt) {return ;/* compute final value */}
});
```

So `0`, `1` are entry, exit functions. All other functions transition an internal state.
All functions can take arguments, eg. `opt`

We create an instance of our newly crafted API,

```
var call = API() // entry
   .whut()       // transition
   .then()       // transition
   .whut();      // transition
```

And call it

```
var result0 = call() // exit
  , result1 = call() // exit
```

Have a look at the (small) [source](https://github.com/0x01/mu-ffsm/blob/master/%C2%B5-ffsm.js) to see how this is implemented.

ps. Used this answer to update docs :D